# Storyboard editor goes blank on xcode when drag'n'drop'ing IBOutlet/IBAction

Tags: ios, interface-builder, uistoryboard, xcode4.3

I have a storyboard with four viewcontrollers. When I drag anything from storyboard to .h file or the other way around the storyboard goes completely blank (white with blue grid lines). It's not a scroll problem, because I can scroll, but there is nothing to scroll to. I can restore the storyboard by clicking another file and then the storyboard again in the project file browser.

The drag'n'drop I've made has been saved to the storyboard though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have the storyboard open in two tabs at the same time in xcode, changing one of them will make that one show an empty storyboard till it has been reloaded. This is fixed by closing one of the tabs and only having one open. I hope this helps someone :)